# Disable “application downloaded from the internet” Message on a Per-App Basis in Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am quite new to MacOs development. I am making mac application which is containing four modules(target apps). I need to launch all submodules when i required. So i am using below.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:appName ofType:extension];
NSWorkspace *workSpace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSString *appPathIs = [workSpace fullPathForApplication:filePath];
[workSpace launchApplication:appPathIs];
```

Here problem when launching module everytime i am getting app downloaded from the internet pop from the system. I need to nullify this pop up.

I have gone through so many i tried everthing still i couldnt able to solve this issue. Here the below things i have used.

1. http://osxdaily.com/2010/09/12/disable-application-downloaded-from-the-internet-message-in-mac-os-x/
2. launch application through NSTask.

If i am using system("open -n applicationPath") pop up not getting in first time. But problem when i am trying to launch second time application is not relaunching.

Please try to help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: High sierra version 10.13.6

Comment: `system("open -n applicationPath")` < `-n` "Open a new instance of the application(s) even if one is already running". What do you expect to happen? Are you quitting the app before trying to relaunch it? Your `NSTask` approach should work, I suggest you show some code and explain exactly what you want to happen, and what is not working.

Comment: @TheNextman In my application resources i have three more projects are there. So i want to run those applications from my application when i want required and i need to be kill when i want. But this application not downloading from app store. It is downloading from our server. So i am getting application dowloaded from the internet when i tried to run main application. Same pop up coming from sub projects also. So i need to avoid that message pop for sub modules.

Comment: @Rajesh, right I understand. But what's your difficulty with `NSTask`? You said it works the first time, but then the second time the application doesn't relaunch. Did you already close the first instance?

Comment: Yes. i closed existing instance and launching new instance. But my exact issue i need to avoid "the app downloading from internet" pop up after launching to new instance. I dont want to get that pop up everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I found the solution. When we run the application from the dmg file which is downloaded from website. It runs in the ROM. So we cant change the file properties in ROM folders.

So we copied those files from ROM folders to user defined folders and we applied

```
 xattr -d -r com.apple.quarantine /userdefinedPath/to/application/
```

Then we can avoid that pop up for child applications.